# Where can I find more information on using Microsoft Windows SLAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

In particular, I'm trying to find out how to use it to differentiate between server and server *core* editions of Windows. The `SLGetWindowsInformation()` looks simple enough to use, but I don't know what info names are available.

SLAPI = [Software Licensing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965829.aspx)

Comment: Neil please indicate if one of the give answers can be accepted...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use GetProductInfo() you can call [SLQueryInformationDWORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specify Kernel-ProductInfo for the name parameter. The returned values are the same as GetProductInfo() :D (at least on my testsystem)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using the [GetProductInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx) API for that, just check the pdwReturnedProductType parameter for one of the server core values.

Example code (Delphi but not hard to translate to c(++)):

```
function IsServerCore: Boolean;
var
  osvi: OSVERSIONINFOEX;
  dwPT: DWORD;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@osvi, SizeOf(osvi));
  osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(osvi);
  Win32Check(GetVersionEx(osvi));

  Win32Check(GetProductInfo(osvi.dwMajorVersion, osvi.dwMinorVersion,
    osvi.wServicePackMajor, osvi.wServicePackMinor, dwPT));

  case dwPT of
    PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE_V,
    PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE_V,
    PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE_V,
    PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_SOLUTIONS_CORE,
    PRODUCT_SOLUTION_EMBEDDEDSERVER_CORE,
    PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM_CORE: Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks except I specifically need to use SLAPI, the GetProductInfo() usage is precisely the function I am tasked with replacing. :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but my understanding is that it requires a very specific switch statement that needs to be updated when new SKU's appear